# Как при клике не сохранять высоту родителя?

Tags: javascript, css

при клике первый раз на кнопку, блоку задаётся класс дисплей flex. Появившийся блок толкает своей высотой тот контент который ниже, но стоит прокрутить до кнопки и клацнуть заново, фокус остаётся на самой кнопке, а не на появившимся контенте, до тех пор пока мы не тронем скролл страницы.
Как этого избежать и при каждом клике заново воспроизводить как в первый раз, желательно предоставить чтиво, почему это так.

```js
const block = document.querySelector('.block_2')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    block.classList.toggle('block_2--show')
})
```

```css
.block-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
 
    background: gray;
}

.block_2 {
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
.block_2--show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-container"> 
  <div class="block">
    <p>
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="block block_2">
    <p>
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn">Клац</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно сделать обычные аккордеоны, чтобы высота была задана только у активного блока.

1. изначально у всех блоков `max-height: 0px; transition: max-height .3s ease;`, у активного `max-height: ...px;`
2. при клике удаляешь у всех пунктов активный класс (проще всего через js пройтись по всем, проверить есть ли класс и удалить)
3. добавляешь активный класс нужному тебе блоку

https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=accordion - тут можешь поискать примеры

Comment: Я не знаю высоту контейнеров, точнее она может быть разной, но знаю одно весьма крупной.

Comment: тебе её нужно на js вычислять